# Discord Bot Sending Multiple Messages in One Line

Tags: python, discord, bots

What I am trying to do is, with Python, create a Discord bot that matches people together. I have basically done it, but the thing is that sometimes it glitches since it is in separate lines. How do I make it all into one message?

```
 guyNames = [
    "test1"
  ]

  girlNames = [
    "test2"
  ]


  if '$matchlovers' in message.content.lower():
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(girlNames))
    await message.channel.send("+")
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(guyNames))
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn

```
await message.channel.send(random.choice(girlNames))
    await message.channel.send("+")
    await message.channel.send(random.choice(guyNames))
```

Into

```
await message.channel.send(random.choice(girlNames) + "\n+\n" + random.choice(guyNames))
```